# Чому °C, а не °Ц?

Tags: скорочення

[Як бачу](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C_(SI)#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%96), одиницї зазвичай пристосовані до вимови за кирилицею: *kg → кг*, *m → м* ітд; в тому числї ті, що від власних імен: *J* від *Joule* → *Дж* від *Джоуль*.

Не перекладаються лише:

- Сталі, але вони і не зовсім одиниці, радше просто [величини](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%83_%D1%84%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%96): стала Планка *h*, число Авогадро *N<sub>A</sub>*, число пі *π* ітд, котрі на друкованому письмі зазвичай позначають лише курсивом, чого не сказати про одиниць.
- Одиницї температур. Можна подумати, що Кельвіна записано кирилицею, але це навряд чи, бо ще є наприклад *°F* i *°R*. Що цїкаво, запис типу *°Ф* ітп рїдко, однак можна зустрїти, але, гадаю, то не норма, а радше лїнивий або машинний переклад.

Тож чим історично зумовлено, що температури записують не відповідними буквами кирилицї, як це зазвичай роблять з іншими одиницями?

Comment: http://www2.linnaeus.uu.se/online/life/6_32.html

Comment: @RomanMikhol не дуже зрозумѣв до чого це.

Answer (score 1):

### Градус Цельсія °C

[°C](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F) — це загальноприйнятий символ для позначення одиниці вимірювання температури за шкалою Цельсія, який широко використовується в побуті та медицині.

**[Стаття 5 Закону України "Про метрологію та метрологічну діяльність"](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/1314-18#Text)** в п.1,2 визначає:

> В Україні застосовуються одиниці вимірювання Міжнародної системи
> одиниць (SI), прийнятої Генеральною конференцією з мір та ваг і
> рекомендованої Міжнародною організацією законодавчої метрології та
> похідні одиниці SI.

А **[Наказ Міністерства економічного розвитку і торгівлі України № 914 від 04 серпня 2015 року](https://www.me.gov.ua/Documents/Download?id=6c4613cf-7f7c-4701-b42c-ca4bf6cfaf2f)** ([у редакції наказу Міністерства
економіки України](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xudtMIWqJ1fjbKrOoNvz_LJIROJd4UBl/view)) уточнює:

> Спеціальна назва похідної одиниці вимірювання температури SІ для
> вираження температури за Цельсієм має міжнародне і відповідне українське позначення °C.

Температура — фізична величина, що є мірою інтенсивності теплового руху атомів і молекул (за ДСТУ 3518-97)

> Температура за Цельсієм t визначається як різниця t = T - T0 між двома
> термодинамічними температурами Т і Т0, де Т0 = 273,15 К. Інтервал або
> різниця температур можуть бути виражені в кельвінах або в градусах
> Цельсія. Одиниця “градус Цельсія” дорівнює одиниці “кельвін”.

**[ПРАВИЛА
застосування одиниць вимірювання і написання назв та позначень одиниць вимірювання і символів величин](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z1022-15.#n45)**

> 3. Назви та позначення одиниць вимірювання друкуються прямим шрифтом з малої літери, за винятком позначень, назви яких походять від прізвищ
>    учених, - вони пишуться з великої літери. Для уніфікації написання
>    позначень це правило поширюється також на позначення дозволених
>    позасистемних одиниць.
> 4. Позначення одиниць вимірювання розташовуються в одному рядку з числовим значенням величини, без перенесення в наступний рядок. Між
>    числом і позначенням одиниці вимірювання залишають проміжок.
>
> Винятки становлять позначення у вигляді єдиного спеціального знака -
> надрядкового індекса, перед яким проміжок не залишають.

Вимірювання температури за Цельсієм здійснюється за [інтервальною системою](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Interval_scale), але не за [системою співвідношення](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ratio_scale), тобто це **відносна шкала**, а не **абсолютна**. Наприклад, об’єкт за температури 20°C не має вдвічі більшої енергії, ніж при 10°C і 0°C не є найнижчим значенням за Цельсієм. Таким чином, градуси Цельсія є корисними при вимірюванням інтервалу, але не володіють характеристиками мір відношень, як-от вага чи відстань.

Comment: Мені здається, що запитується чому з цими одиницями не так як з іншими.

Comment: @Yola ви все правильно зрозумѣли. Причому там мова не лише про Цельсія. Треба читати далѣ за заголовка.

Comment: @Yola, тому що так визначено Законом України і державними установчими Актами, не зумовлено історично. А якщо вас цікавить моя думка, то спробую припустити, що ще пов'язано с особливостями кодування символів UTF-8 на Windows-1251.

Comment: Я теж не розумію цієї відповіді. У запитанні прямо вказано: «чому?» і дається посилання на Вікіпедію. Яка, у свою чергу, має посилання на законодавчу базу. Ця відповідь також дає посилання на законодавчу базу, але це навряд чи містить відповідь на запитання «чому?». Окремим пунктом зазначене «спеціальна назва **похідної** одиниці» для температури свідчить, що «основною» одиницею є Кельвін, а Цельсій є «похідною», бо він широко використовується у побуті тощо. Але це не означає, що ця величина «особлива» саме тим, що пишеться латинкою.

Comment: @RomanMikhol правові акти теж можна пояснювати гісторічно. Не цѣкавить ваша думка, тим паче вона дуже абсурдна, бо можна зробити декотрі можливі хибні висновки: 1) запис зіявився в сучасну компʼютерну епоху (сумнѣваю ся); 2) ранѣше було гинакше (можливо, але де докази); 3) так само мало бути з гиншими одиницями (а це не так).

Comment: ASCII-кодів на всіх охочих для кожної мови не вистачило, тому так.

Comment: А історично вся українська метрологія є похідною від совєтської. Ви можете створити Петицію і зібрати необхідну кількість голосів, щоб створити відповідний Законопроект для внесення змін до Закону. Або можете обратися народним депутатом і розробити такий Законопроект самостійно, якщо нагальніших справ не маєте.